# Firestore Hook Lacks Permission to Call Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I have a Firebase/GCP project with a cloud function that installs a Firestore database hook:

index.ts

```js
export const onCreatePost = functions.firestore.document("/posts/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot) => {
      ...
    });
```

The function triggers every time a new document is created in the Firestore collection "posts", but it fails immediately with an error. The log shows `Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "iam.serviceAccounts.actAs" for the resource "******************@gcp-sa-cloudtasks.iam.gserviceaccount.com" (or the resource may not exist).` I'm not sure which principal lacks the correct permissions. I'm also not sure why it wants to access a resource seemingly related to Google Cloud Tasks. Finally, I've checked IAM settings to ensure that the service account mentioned in the log has a role that grants the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` (although I'm not sure that matters, as it doesn't seem that the mentioned service account is the one missing permissions).

In the Cloud Functions console, the principal ******************@gcp-sa-cloudtasks.iam.gserviceaccount.com is listed as a Cloud Functions Invoker.

What permissions do I need to grant in order for a Firestore hook to call a cloud function?

Comment: How did you deploying the Cloud Function?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Firebase CLI, `firebase deploy`

Comment: Have a look at this github [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/issues/249)